# Concatenate some strings into a global variable in C#

Tags: c#, global-variables

i'm having a problem . I'm trying to make an application in C# (Windows Form Application) and i'm stuck into something.
I want to do a log-in form like in the photo. For username i'm having a combo-box where i can choose the user , but for password i want to place some buttons(like in the photo) , and when i press the button 1 for example , i want to have a string which is 1 .After that i will place 2 ,and i want to concatenate 1 and 2 into that string . Do you know how can i do that

[image: The UI]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Fantastic question. However, I would recommend utilizing some of SO's text decorations and formats to make a clearer question. In addition, please include all source code related to your attempt at this implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I believe you have one event for each button. In each event you could just sum the values to a global variable or directly change the textbox. Like this:

```
txtPassword.Text += "0"; //the 0 button
```

It will change the textbox value and when you click "Sign in" you can get the txtPassword.Text as the final string.

You can also declare a string or StringBuilder globally and append the value in every button click, tho this won't change the textbox text directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder to concatenate strings.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(a);// where "a" is your input character
```

And whenever you get a new character input call builder.Append(a);

In the end you get your final string by calling builder.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on the answer from @LeoFormaggi, you could have a single event handler for all the numeric buttons (i.e., one that every button's click handler points to).  Then, in the handler:

```
var buttonText = (sender as Button)?.Text;
txtPassword.Text += buttonText ?? String.Empty;
```

Don't forget to make that textbox be a password field (by setting the PasswordChar property).

You don't want to bother with a StringBuilder here. It's normally the right tool for concatenating strings, but it buys you nothing in this case since you want the result to appear immediately in the text box. In this case it would simply add overhead for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

i want to thank you, i made my solution like this :

`private void nb6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            password_box.Text += "6";
        }`

in every button event that i have, the password_box (which is my textbox) and i concatenate everytime the string that i want(in this case is number 6 )

Thank you and have a nice day . :)

Comment: If you are going to use @LeoFormaggi's solution, you should accept it and up vote it if you haven't yet done that. For what it's worth, my variation requires less code, but Leo's is a fine solution